# How to highlight the duplicate value in kendo grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

This is my logic to prevent duplicate values in the controller

```
public ActionResult ProviderType_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<ProviderTypeMasterViewModel> ProviderTypeMasterList)
    {
        var results = new List<ProviderTypeMasterViewModel>();
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("ProviderTypeMastersController ProviderType_Create Start");
            foreach (var ProviderTypeMaster in ProviderTypeMasterList)
            {
                TblProviderTypeMaster ptm = new ProviderTypeMasterViewModel().ToModel(ProviderTypeMaster);
                var provd = _context.TblProviderTypeMasters.Where(p => p.ProviderTypeName == ProviderTypeMaster.ProviderTypeName).ToList();
                if (provd != null && provd.Count() == 0)
                {
                    if (ProviderTypeMasterList != null && ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        string userID = GetUserID();
                        providerTypeMasterService.SaveProviderTypeMaster(ProviderTypeMaster, userID);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    duplicate = true;
                    return this.Json(new DataSourceResult
                    {
                        Errors = "my custom error"
                    });
                }
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("ProviderTypeMastersController ProviderType_Create Complete");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError("ProviderTypeMastersController ProviderType_Create Failed - " + e.Message);
        }
        return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

**I show the error in an alert message using the error event of the kendo grid in my view**. Now I need help on these two things.

1.) Is there any other way I could show the error message without an alert message. Like a label? If so where should I hide the label after the duplicate is removed?

2.) I want to highlight the particular value of the grid in which the user has entered the duplicate value. A change like changing the particular grid value to red when id is duplicate and remove the red color when the user changes the duplicate value to a unique value.

I am a beginner and I am stuck here. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add your error to ModelState:

```
public JsonResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<ProviderTypeMasterViewModel> ProviderTypeMasterList)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var ProviderTypeMaster in ProviderTypeMasterList)
        {
            TblProviderTypeMaster ptm = new ProviderTypeMasterViewModel().ToModel(ProviderTypeMaster);
            if (_context.TblProviderTypeMasters.Any(p => p.ProviderTypeName == ProviderTypeMaster.ProviderTypeName))
            {
                 ModelState.AddModelError("ProviderTypeName", "ProviderType already exists");
            }
            else
            {
                if (ProviderTypeMasterList != null)
                {
                    string userID = GetUserID();
                    providerTypeMasterService.SaveProviderTypeMaster(ProviderTypeMaster, userID);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to format Kendo Grid Column value with conditionally chosen action you can use one of the suitable examples below. For more information: [How Do I Have Conditional Logic in a Column Client Template?](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-have-conditional-logic-in-a-column-client-template).

***UI for Javascript:***

```
{
    field: "EmployeeName", type: "string", width: "55px", title: "Employee Name", 
       template: "#= GetEditTemplate(data) #"
}
```

***UI for MVC:***

```
...
columns.Bound(t => t.EmployeeName).Title("Status Name").Template(@<text></text>)
    .ClientTemplate("#= GetEditTemplate(data)#").Width("55px");
...
```

Here is the method used in the example:

```
<script>
//Change the color of the cell value according to the given condition
function GetEditTemplate(data) {
    var html;
 
    if (data.StatusID == 1) {
        html = kendo.format(
        //"<a class=\"k-button\" href='" + '@Url.Action("Edit1", "Controller")' + "/{0}" + " '>Edit</a>  ",
        "<span class='text-success'>" +
        data.EmployeeName
        + "</span>"
        );
    }
    else {
        html = kendo.format(
        //"<a class=\"k-button\" href='" + '@Url.Action("Edit2", "Controller")' + "/{0}" + " '>Edit</a>  ",
        "<span class='text-danger'>Cancel</span>"
        );
    }
    return html;
}
</script>
```